# AIR iOS and Android login

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am building an app in AIR/AS3 for iOS and Android which requires user information to be submitted and stored in a remote DB. I guess I will need to build a register/sign in screen but just wondering what the best method to store the session information in the app.

I would like it that if the user closes the app the session remains when they start it again. I currently have suspend on exit in the app.xml file. Should I just remove this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Probably worth giving a flip through of this for some high level ideas (without the seminar it's difficult to get details out of this)
http://www.slideshare.net/marcocasario/local-persistent-data-with-actionscript-3-and-air

If you're using Flex I'd suggest starting here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSb0a29bf92525419c-54dd253312afbec3ecb-8000.html

Otherwise either using the File/FileStream classes and an XML file or the SQLite options are both good as well depending on what you need to save/restore and how you'll be working with the data.

Comment: I really only need the email address of the user to retrieve information from remote source but thinking I need a password too otherwise anyone can get any other persons information. Its not sensitive data at all but still. I guess I could store the session information in local SQLite and put a time stamp on it to log out after say 2 days of inactivity. Then validate the SQLite information with the remote DB and if valid skip the sign in/register pages.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about sqllite, xml files, and php files. Make the flash file call a xml file that talks to a php file that talks to the mysql server.
Otherwise look here: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-a-flash-login-system-using-php-and-mysql-part-1/